# "-Drun.profiles=.." is not working when trying to execute Spring Boot jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to execute the following:

```
C:\Users\Homeuser>java -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=testpass -Drun.profiles.active=dev C:\testproj\target\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However, the version that runs uses the properties that are specified in the `application-local.properties` file, and not from the `application-dev.properties` file as I expected. I know this because the local version uses an H2 db with fake data, and the -dev profile connects to a real database with real data, and what I saw was the fake data. In my `application.properties` file, I have the following setting:

`spring.profiles.active=local`

This problem is only happening when I am building a jar first then executing it. When I use the following command from Eclipse maven run profile:

`clean spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev -Djasypt.encryptor.password=testpass`

It correctly loads up the expected profile. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `run.profiles` is a property which comes from the `spring-boot` maven plugin. So it only works if you use that to run your application. If you want to activate a plugin when using the `jar` command, specify the property `spring.profiles.active=dev`.

Comment: I tried `spring.profiles.active=dev` and `-spring.profiles.active=dev`. In the first case, the error was `Unable to access jarfile spring.profiles.active=dev` and in the second case it was a fatal error saying it is an unrecognized option.

Comment: If you want to set the property in the command line, it's `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` (as you have done with run.profiles).